# Issue parsing data through JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

I am getting the issue when parsing the following string data. Please let me know how can I parse it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var abc = ['hello','Yes','No'];
     alert(abc);
     var abc1 = abc.split(",");
     $.each(abc1,function(i){
         alert(abc1[i]);
     });
});
```

I want to parse the `abc` value. I need `hello`, `yes` and `no` value in variable so I can use it.

Comment: abc var here in your case is an array.. so you can just parse it using abc[0], abc[1] or abc[2]

Comment: please format your code sample to make it easier to read

Answer (score 1):

`abc` is already an array and an array doesn't have a `split` function.

just make it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var abc=['hello','Yes','No'];
     $.each(abc,function(i){
         alert(abc[i]);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array, not a string. You can loop the array:

```
var abc=['hello','Yes','No'];
for (var i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
    console.log(abc[i]);
}
```

Or make an actual string:

```
var abc = "hello,Yes,No";
var split = abc.split(",");

for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    console.log(split[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var abc=['hello','Yes','No'];
    alert(abc);
    for (var i = 0; i < abc.length; i++) 
    {   
        alert(abc[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing to SO!  While this may answer the question, offering no explanation does not help explain to the OP **why** this is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach`

> The forEach() method executes a provided function once per array
>   element.

**ES5 way:**

```
var abc=['hello','Yes','No'];
abc.forEach(function(e){
  alert(e);
})
```

**ES6 way:**

```
var abc=['hello','Yes','No'];
abc.forEach(e=>{
  alert(e);
})
```

You dont need jQuery to iterate an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .forEach method from Array Object:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var abc=['hello','Yes','No'];
    alert(abc);
    abc.forEach(function(el){
        console.log(el);
    });
});
```

For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, all you need is `abc` in one variable? You can use
`var jointAbc = abc.join("");` for that. If you want them separate than you already have the array.